# No signal on my HD TV raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, retropie

On my pi 3, I have fixed hot plugging HDMI by adding HDMI hot plug to 1, boost to 4 and mode to 2 in my config.txt file.

However, when I plug it into my LG HD TV/monitor it just says no signal. Any ideas? I know it's working as it's fine on my other TV.

This is a full HD TV and it works on my other TV, so I've no idea what else to try. I need this to work as it's for retropie.

Answer (score 1):

check out tvservice

it should give you information on the connection status of the HDMI.

tvservice -n Will show you the name of the device connected.

(by the way, why mode 2?  That's only 480p)

Otherwise, it could be totally unrelated to the Pi.  Bad HDMI cable, wrong input on the TV...